# How to remove the cost label after shipping method? opencart

Tags: opencart

How to remove the cost label after shipping method?
I tried to solve but failed
Please help

[image: fig 1]

Comment: If you have tried, then where is the code you have tried, and if you have failed, then where is the error message/failure description? Did you visit the [help](http://stackoverflow.com/help) section?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

Open File: `catalog/view/theme/<your theme>/template/checkout/shipping_method.tpl`

**Find & remove code:**

```
<td style="text-align: right;"><label for="<?php echo $quote['code']; ?>"><?php echo $quote['text']; ?></label></td>
```

and then check it.

Comment: I tried remove this but with unknown reason, it's still there

Comment: @JamesFong I have Update answer. Please check & try again. Thanks.